# How to run codeigniter-in-subdirectory-on-nginx-404

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx

We need to run subdirectory secure named folder CodeIgniter files. when we hit secure.domain.com then it gives 404 error (CI) but we need to call controller method so we need to run below URL
http://secure.domain.com/secure

our Nginx.conf file contains the following syntax:-

```html
server {
  server_name secure.domain.com;
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
 root /var/www/secure/;
 index index.php;
 ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/ssl/domain/www.erp2.domain.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/ssl/erp.domain.com.key;
  location @iparksmart {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_read_timeout 500;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://iparksmart;
  }
location /secure/ {
    alias  /var/www/secure/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_pass    unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }  }
  location /cable {
    proxy_pass http://iparksmart;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
  }
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Comment: What is exactly what you want to achieve? You want to call controller methods like https://secure.domain.com/secure/controllerMethod?

Comment: need to call secure.domain.com/secure and secure is our controller

Comment: Can you try to remove the location block /secure/ and move the contents of it to the main server block? (Remove all the duplicate lines ofcourse and the alias line)

Comment: when we remove this then server refuse to connect..

Comment: Try taking a look at this. Official NGINX configuration. Maybe this will help you further. https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/codeigniter/